# plotting unsmooth normal distribution in r

Tags: r

Dears, I have air temperature data and I need to plot the normal distribution for three selected decades with unsmooth curves. The figure that I am looking for is something similar to Fig 2 [here](https://www.giss.nasa.gov/research/briefs/hansen_17/), where I can see the fluctuations of tempratures for each curve (i.e., the noises).

Here is an example of an online data and codes:

```
Cowtan<-read.table("http://www-users.york.ac.uk/~kdc3/papers/coverage2013/had4_krig_v2_0_0.txt", header=F)
names(Cowtan)<-c("Year", "Temperature", "Uncertainty1", "Uncertainty2", "Uncertainty3") #Name the columns

S1850s<-subset(Cowtan, Year<1860) #Get subsets of each decade
S1950s<-subset(Cowtan, Year>=1950 & Year<1960)
S2007<-subset(Cowtan, Year>=2007 & Year<2017)
D1850s=density(S1850s$Temperature) #Get the density kernals
D1950s<-density(S1950s$Temperature)
D2007<-density(S2007$Temperature)
plot(D1850s, main="Bell curve of  temperatures during selected decades", xlab="Temperature anomalies (ºC)",xlim=c(-1.1,1.3), ylim=c(0,3), lwd=1.5)
points(D2007, type="l",col="red", lwd=1.5)
points(D1950s, type="l",col="blue", lwd=1.5)
legend("topleft", legend=c("1850s", "1950s", "2007-2016"), col=c("black", "blue", "red"), lwd=2)
```

Comment: What is an "unsmooth normal distribution"?

Answer (score 1):

How about just generating points of a normal distribution and adding them to the plot??

```
Cowtan<-read.table("http://www-users.york.ac.uk/~kdc3/papers/coverage2013/had4_krig_v2_0_0.txt", header=F)
names(Cowtan)<-c("Year", "Temperature", "Uncertainty1", "Uncertainty2", "Uncertainty3") #Name the columns

S1850s<-subset(Cowtan, Year<1860) #Get subsets of each decade
S1950s<-subset(Cowtan, Year>=1950 & Year<1960)
S2007<-subset(Cowtan, Year>=2007 & Year<2017)
D1850s=density(S1850s$Temperature) #Get the density kernals
D1950s<-density(S1950s$Temperature)
D2007<-density(S2007$Temperature)
plot(D1850s, main="Bell curve of  temperatures during selected decades", xlab="Temperature anomalies (ºC)",xlim=c(-1.1,1.3), ylim=c(0,3), lwd=1.5)
points(D2007, type="l",col="red", lwd=1.5)
points(D1950s, type="l",col="blue", lwd=1.5)

norm.dist <- rnorm(1000000, 0, 0.3)
points(density(norm.dist), type = "l", col="green")


legend("topleft", legend=c("1850s", "1950s", "2007-2016", "norm dist"), col=c("black", "blue", "red", "green"), lwd=2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of an "unsmooth curve" similar to that shown in Figure 2.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(10000)
plot(density(x, bw=0.01))
```

[image]

As you can see, I set the smoothing bandwidth `bw` to a very small value so that the density plot seems "unsmoothed". The crucial point in this graph is the availability of a large number of observations.
Using your data the final plot is like this:

[image]

I hope this can help you.

P.S. In the figure above I used the `kernel="epanechnikov"` option in the `density` function.